# How to write many functions in one JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax

How can I write this two (or more) same functions in one - to compress JS data - they are same functions but different css. It is for highlighting different imgs on hover specific li  - one li for one img

```
$(".class1").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".class2").addClass("highlight");
});

$(".class3").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".class4").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following, but i would advise you to rethink your css (class) - structure as  @Tushar suggested!

```
[['.class1', '.class2'], ['.class3', '.class4']].forEach(function(value) {
    $(value[0]).mouseenter(function(event) {
        $(value[1]).addClass("highlight"); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Add a common class to all the elements of interest and then bind event on the common class.
2. Use `data-*` attribute to store the selector of the element on which the class `highlight` is to be added.
3. Use the selector on `data` attribute to perform actions on it

Javascript:

```
$('.myClass').mouseenter(function() {
    $($(this).data('target')).addClass('highlight');
});
```

And in HTML, add `data-target` attribute.

```
<div data-target=".class2" class="class1 myClass">Lorem</div>
<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^          -->
<div data-target=".class3" class="class2 myClass">Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Thx, tihs is good way how to do it but I mean how to rewrite the previous js, just to make it more simple withouth change html code, is it possible to do it that way?

Comment: @Rudi I've added the code of JS too, you just have to bind event only once using common class

Answer (score 2):

Following @Tushar's answer with a single line you can add multiple `class` with a `,` separated values as below:

Add a `data-*` (*->Any value) say `to` to your elements like one below:

```
<div data-to=".class2" class="class1">First Class</div>
<div data-to=".class3" class="class2">Second Class</div>
```

Then with JS:

```
$(".class1,.class2").mouseenter(function(){
    $($(this).data('to')).addClass("highlight"); 
});
```